# how to sum between 2 column data in SQL

Tags: sql

As title, i would like to sum 2 column data and show the result in another column. Below is an example, kindly advise. Thanks.

this is my data:

```
SELECT
ES.SHPMNT_REF AS "File No",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "20'",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "40'"

FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES
```

The table is like:

```
File No    20'     40'
 000123     3       4
 000124     1       2
```

what I want is like:

```
File No    20'     40'     Total
 000123     3       4        7
 000124     1       2        3
```

The "total" is not in the database column, is it a dummy column.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as 
(SELECT
ES.SHPMNT_REF AS "File No",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "20'",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "40'"

FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES)
select "File No", "20'", "40'", "20'" + "40'" as "Total"
from data;
```

EDIT: If your backend doesn't support "with CTE":

```
select "File No", "20'", "40'", "20'" + "40'" as "Total"
from (SELECT
ES.SHPMNT_REF AS "File No",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "20'",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "40'"

FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES) data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CTE`

```
with cte as
(SELECT
ES.SHPMNT_REF AS "File No",

(SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "20'",

(SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "40'"

FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES )
Select *, [20'] + [40'] as "Total" from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `+`.

```
SELECT
ES.SHPMNT_REF AS "File No",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "20'",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "40'",

    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF)
    +
    (SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS WHERE
    EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "Total"
FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` to add two values. Move your aggregation query to the `FROM` clause (or `WITH` clause, if you like this better) for convenience.

```
select
  es.shpmnt_ref,
  coalesce(eso.extra20, 0) as ex20,
  coalesce(eso.extra40, 0) as ex40,
  coalesce(eso.extra20, 0) + coalesce(eso.extra40, 0) as total
from brdb.export_shipment es
left join
(
  select
    shpmnt_ref,
    max(extra_20_containers) as extra20,
    max(extra_40_containers) as extra40
  from export_shipping_orders
  group by shpmnt_ref
) eso on eso.shpmnt_ref = es.shpmnt_ref;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using the '+' operator

```
SELECT
ES.SHPMNT_REF AS "File No",

(SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS 
WHERE EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "20'",

(SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS 
WHERE EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF) AS "40'"

((SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_20_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS 
WHERE EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF)
+ 
(SELECT MAX(EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.EXTRA_40_CONTAINERS) FROM EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS 
WHERE EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF)) AS "Total"

FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES
```